# Unexplained Mathematical Passage in Fourier Series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, spectra

just as an FYI, this is an exercise from Digital Signal Processing by Proakis & Manolakis 4th Edition.

I need to calculate the spectrum X(F) of a signal given by a graph. That part was easy and I was able to set up the equation. The sign i s a periodic sinusoidal signal of the type:

$$ Asin(\frac{\pi t}{\tau}) $$

The signal is periodic with period $\tau$

So I want to calculate the Fourier series in the following way:
$$ C_k = \frac{1}{\tau}\int_{0}^{\tau} Asin(\frac{\pi t}{\tau}) e^{-j2\pi k\frac{t}{\tau} }dt$$
$$ C_k = \frac{1}{j2\tau}\int_{0}^{\tau} [{e^{j\pi k\frac{t}{\tau} } - e^{-j\pi k\frac{t}{\tau} }]e^{-j2\pi k\frac{t}{\tau} }dt}$$
$$ C_k = \frac{A}{j2\tau} \biggr[ \frac{e^{j\pi (1-2k)\frac{t}{\tau}}}{\frac{j \pi}{2}(1-2k)} - \frac{e^{-j\pi (1+2k)\frac{t}{\tau}}}{\frac{-j \pi}{2}(1+2k)}\biggr]_0^{\tau}$$

What I do not understand is how the next passage is derived:

$$ \frac{A}{\pi} \biggr[ \frac{1}{1-2k} + \frac{1}{1+2k} \biggr] $$

The problem goes on doing calculation that I can follow, but i need to know: what has been applied here? My calculations give other values. Here is what I got from the integration:

$$ C_k = \frac{A}{2j\tau} \biggr[  \frac{e^{j\pi (1-2k)}-1}{j \frac{\pi}{\tau}(1-2k} -\frac{e^{-j\pi (1+2k)}-1}{-j \frac{\pi}{\tau}(1+2k)} \biggr]  $$

the multiplying the extrnal j and factoring the $\pi$ I get 
$$ C_k = \frac{A}{2\pi} \biggr[ - \frac{e^{j\pi (1-2k)}-1}{(1-2k)} -\frac{e^{-j\pi (1+2k)}-1}{(1+2k)} \biggr]  $$

....am I wrong? If so, can anyone help me understand what I missed?

Edit: Here is a link to the image that has teh full book passage:[image]

Comment: $\mathrm{e}^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)$, i.e. use [Euler's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula).

Comment: I know that in some way Euelers Formula is necessary and I am aware of it. Could you explain in further detail on how the exercise used this formula? Thanks

Comment: They just plug in $t=\tau$ and $t=0$ and subtract and simplify. Note that $e^{jn\pi}$ is $1$ for an even integer $n$ (including zero) and $-1$ for an odd integer $n$. They also mostly cancelled out the $j \pi/2$ terms with the outside. I'm not entirely sure where the $\tau$ went...

Comment: Ok I think I got this then. The note you just told helped me better understand...